# MIgrate TFVC 2015 repositories to Github

Tags: github, tfs-2015

searched on stackoverflow and found in past https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs tool is being used. Found this tool is not being updated for last 2-3 years.

Shall I continue to use this tool? Suggest any other tool please.

We have multiple Team Projects each with multiple branches.

Comment: Tool recommendation requests are off-topic for Stack Overflow. You found something that does what you want. Try it. See if it works. Experiment. If you have problems that you can't figure out, you can ask a question about those problems.

Answer (score 0):

As workaround. You can:

1. Upgrade your TFS server to new version (minimum TFS 2017 Update 2).
2. [Import you TFVC repo to GIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-from-tfvc?view=azure-devops).
3. [Publish your new Git repo to Githib](https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line).